# launch a second python script independently from the first

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, flags

this is in reference to this [project](https://github.com/skewballfox/pomodoro_lock).

I'm trying to launch the pomodoro_lock script from the toggler, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I want to launch it in the background so that the rest of the script can run, but I want it to continue running after the toggle script closes. Unless I'm misunderstanding the way the subprocess module works, popen launches the process as a thread that is independent from but dependent on the initial python script(i.e. once the script ends, the process will no longer be running in the background). I want this to launch the script and then exit shortly thereafter(to prevent conflicts between multiple instances modifying the same flags)

this may be just because I'm still a novice, but I don't think the normal approaches to multi-threading work for the above mentioned reason.

Comment: From what I see you are using `subprocess.call` instead of `Popen`. `call` blocks the python script until the process ends.

Comment: I'm aware, I was asking more about something I hadn't implemented yet. Sorry, I had forgot that I wrote that before I pushed a commit for adding the license. I started to write that as I realized I couldn't use call, then I looked up how to multi-thread and realized that's not what I needed either.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, after testing out popen that it does actually launch an independent instance. after the program exited I confirmed that the launched script was still running with `ps -aux | grep python3`. the script had persisted after the exit of the first.

not sure if I should delete this question or leave it here for the next person trying to fumble there way to victory. if I should delete it, just leave a comment here.